# Pandas drop rows in time series with less than x observation

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with timeseries data in Pandas (timestamp used as index). I am doing some filtering on my dataset and end up with a dataframe that mostly contains consecutive observations (one-minute data). However, there are also time intervals with only one or a few minutes of obervations. These I would like to exclude. How can I get hold of those short intervals using sth like:

```
df = df.drop(df[<some boolean condition>].index)
```

```
timestamp               value     
2018-01-08 06:13:00     143
2018-01-08 06:14:00     324
2018-01-08 06:15:00     324
2018-01-08 06:16:00     324
2018-01-08 06:17:00     324
2018-01-08 06:20:00     324(remove)
2018-01-08 06:35:00     324
2018-01-08 06:36:00     324
2018-01-08 06:37:00     324
2018-01-08 06:38:00     324
2018-01-08 06:39:00     324
2018-01-08 06:40:00     324
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert index to Series
s = df.index.to_series()
#test if 1 Minute difference, then cumulative sum
a = s.diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='Min')).cumsum()

#filter if counts of cumulative value greater like N, e.g. 3
N = 3
df = df[a.map(a.value_counts()).gt(N)]
print (df)
                     value
timestamp                 
2018-01-08 06:13:00    143
2018-01-08 06:14:00    324
2018-01-08 06:15:00    324
2018-01-08 06:16:00    324
2018-01-08 06:17:00    324
2018-01-08 06:35:00    324
2018-01-08 06:36:00    324
2018-01-08 06:37:00    324
2018-01-08 06:38:00    324
2018-01-08 06:39:00    324
2018-01-08 06:40:00    324
```

Comment: I tried to make it clearer. It´s not so much about the one-hour time spans but rather about getting rid of just single observations...

Comment: @N.Foe - [Is possible dont post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ? Because not possible copy data from picture here.